# Call a function in background thread with c#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a function Init() and in which there are lot's of functions are calling of Product class. But there is one function "UpdateProduct()" has a large number of records around 3000 rows and due to this Init() function is taking too many time to execute. So to improve the performance I wanted the calling of UpdateProduct() function should be Async. And for that I wanted to use Async & Await. I tried to do that but could able to do it. So can anyone suggest the way for that. Please check below-

```
Public Int Init()
{
    Product p = new Product();
    Int productId = 10;
    Int UserId  = 101;

    Int count = 4;

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.XYZ();
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.ABC();
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.MNC();
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.UpdateProduct(productId,UserId);
    }

    ------------etc (other stuff)------
}
```

Please check the Product class below-

```
public class Product
{
      public void UpdateProduct(int productId,int UserId)
      {
          Category cat = new Category();

          var catList = cat.GetCategory();

          for(int i=0; i< catList.count; i++)  //there are 3000 records here
          {
             --------------some process--------
             --------------- --------
          }
      }

}
```

FYI, I want the UpdateProduct method should call in background until other functionalities should execute and should wait(await) once all of the other functionalities are completed.

Comment: Which part about using async and await didnt work?

Comment: Well for starters, `UpdateProduct` doesn't return anything, so it's gonna be a bit tough assigning anything to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use `async-await` approach you need be ready to change all related method to be asynchronous too from UI to dataccess.

First change `UpdateProduct` to be asynchronous (add suffix `Async` to the method)

```
public class Product
{
    public async Task UpdateProductAsync(int productId,int UserId)
    {
        Category cat = new Category();

        // this need to be changed to async too
        var categories = await cat.GetCategoryAsync(); 

        foreach(var category in categories)
        {
            // process result of GetCategoryAsync
        }
    }
}
```

Then `Init` method need to be changed to asynchronous too. Because method return `int` return type will be `Task<int>`

```
Public async Task<int> InitAsync()
{
   Product p = new Product();
   int productId = 10;
   int UserId  = 101;

   int count = 4;

   // .. execute all methods before UpdateProduct

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = await p.UpdateProductAsync(productId,UserId);
    }

    // execute all methods after Updateproduct

    return result;
}
```

And of course the method which uses `InitAsync` need to be changed to "support" async.

With approach above you will use "correct" `async-await` approach which will use only one thread and will release UI thread while waiting for response.
Notice that this approach was designed mostly for working with IO devices such as File, web service, databases.

On the other hand you can wrap you synchronous `UpdateProduct` method with another thread and wait for it's completes. This solution will work, but will not be so effective as previous because will use one extra thread which will do nothing - only waits for response.

Another case - if your bottle neck is categories processing

```
var categories = await cat.GetCategory(); 

foreach(var category in categories)
{
    // heavy-long calculation
}
```

In this case better to use Parallel approach by using your user's machines cores effectively.

```
var categories = await cat.GetCategoryAsync().ToList(); 
Parallel.ForEach(categories, Calculate);

private sub Calculate(Category category)
{
    // Do your calculation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public async Int Init()
{
    Product p = new Product();
    Int productId = 10;
    Int UserId  = 101;

    Int count = 4;

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.XYZ();
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.ABC();
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.MNC();
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
         await p.UpdateProduct(productId,UserId);
    }

    ------------etc (other stuff)------
}
```

and

```
public class Product
{
      public Task UpdateProduct(int productId,int UserId)
      {
          Category cat = new Category();

          var catList = cat.GetCategory();

          for(int i=0; i< catList.count; i++)  //there are 3000 records here
          {
             --------------some process--------
             --------------- --------
          }
      }

}
```

Comment: It won't be `await p.UpdateProduct(productId,UserId);` It will be `var result = p.UpdateProduct(productId,UserId);` and when everything else is completed, they will just need `Task.WaitAll(result);`

Comment: no it's not required,you can use `Task` to indicate that a method won't return anything.

Comment: not required, but if you put await there, then the whole reason for having it async is killed.

Comment: are you sure , why is that ?

Comment: if you put `await`, it means you are waiting for the async task to complete to move on.

Comment: no brother `Task.Wait` blocks until the task is complete, while `await` keeps processing and when the task is complete, it enqueues a message that says "pick up where you left off after that await"

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code I Hope This Code Help You

Create Your **Method** Like

```
public Task<string> TestMethod()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
     //your code Here
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

and **Call** it

```
async protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await TestMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product
{
    public async Task UpdateProduct(int productId, int UserId)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //this will simulate your process
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            //Category cat = new Category();

            //var catList = cat.GetCategory();

            //for (int i = 0; i < catList.count; i++)  //there are 3000 records here
            //{
            //    --------------some process--------
            //    -------------- - --------
            //}
        });            
    }

    public int XYZ()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int ABC()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int MNC()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then your Init method can look like this (note that while UpdateProduct is executing, other methods will execute)

```
/// <summary>
/// Async Init method
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Awaitable task with int as return value</returns>
public async Task<int> Init()
{
    var p = new Product();
    var productId = 10;
    var UserId = 101;
    Task updateProduct = null;

    var count = 4;

    if (count > 0)
    {
        //this will start UpdateProduct method in different thread (asynchronously)
        updateProduct = p.UpdateProduct(productId, UserId);
    }

    //while UpdateProduct method is executing, other methods can be executed
    if (count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.XYZ();
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.ABC();
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        var result = p.MNC();
    }

    //------------etc (other stuff)------

    //before leaving method, ensure UpdateProduct has finished its job
    if (updateProduct != null)
        await updateProduct;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried with your example it seems it's working but after calling await updateProduct its not returning to the Init method for a long time. So I am not sure whether it's working fine or not. Also I wanted to know what is the use of Thread.Sleep(10000); here.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(10000) will pause executing thread for 10 seconds. It is there only to show you, that while executing a thread with a lot of work (taking 10 seconds) other commands (in different thread - Main thread) will continue. Depending on your case, you do not have to await updateProduct task. But it depends on situation.

Comment: but once execute await statement it's not coming back to the main function. Is this because of loop ? Do we need to use Task.WaitAll() ?

Comment: Looping over 3000 rows in UpdateProduct takes some time as you have mentioned in your original post. That causes the executing thread to be busy for that time. By writing Task.Run(() => ...) I created the new thread for this job. I put await keyword before Task.Run to say that in UpdateProduct method, I want to wait for task to finish. Await then notifies the caller (Init method), that it is waiting for a specific task. Init method then can make a decision, whether it needs to wait for this task to finish or not. If you remove await updateProduct, Init method will finish before UpdateProduct